# eclipse loads web.xml incorrectly to tomcat

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

And I'm having issue in running spring project on tomcat in eclipse(mars).

My project is built with maven and basing on profiles, the web.xml file is built. So here is how dev profile is defined as following:

```
<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  ...
  <properties>
    ...
    <welcomePage>devIndexPage.xhtml</welcomePage>
</properties>
```

Then in the web.xml I have following definition with a placeholder:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>${welcomePage}</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

After building a project, I'm opening WAR file and can see that web.xml has welcome file config like (placeholder replaced with value of dev profile):

```
<welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>devIndexPage.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So until now everything is OK, but when I run project on tomcat7 in eclipse, looks like welcome file value is ${welcomePage}. In other words, looks like eclipse+tomcat load web.xml without replacing placeholder.

I'm sure that my configuration should work, because I successfully run it manually on tomcat without using eclipse. So I guess that eclipse copies project wrongly to wtpwebapps folder.

Could you please give me suggestions what should I configure on eclipse in order to load web.xml correctly?

In addition I'm providing tomcat overview:

[image]

**Edit**
So I already figured out that web.xml, which is copied to `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myapp` has as following `<welcome-file>${welcomePage}</welcome-file>`. So any idea why placeholder wasn't replaced wen web app was deployed in this folder?

Comment: Please post the plugin of pom.xml which does the placeholder replacing.

Answer (score 1):

The replace of expressions is a maven feature Independent of the ide used. Try mvn tomcat:run instead of eclipse.